# PHP SMTP on localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send an email when someone press a submit button, first of all is it possible to configure the SMTP through localhost?

I have some code but it is too extensive,as secret information, and it is in a different language so i won't post it here.

I just would like to know the steps to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: _possible to configure the SMTP through localhost_ YES, but my answer on how to do it is also secret

Comment: Using Windows or a *NIX?

Comment: I'm using a Mac so *NIX

Comment: how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you got a mail server? Or are you trying to send through a Google/Yahoo type account

Comment: I suggest you look at [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases)

Comment: I Have a mail server and I'm not sure if the problem right now is the code or some extra step... I'll try some different code and post it here